# Change dropdown select option depend on datepicker select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to create a search that has as option to choose a day.

I want to give that option with drop-down select and with a calendar as well.

I am using Bootstrap and JQuery-UI datepicker.

My code is working, both of options are working BUT

I want when user select a day on calendar to change dynamically the date on dropdown as well.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="input-group col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 search">
      <label class="bd-form-label" style="float: left;width: 100%;">Dates</label>
         <select name="name" id="name_id" style="width: 80%;float: left;">
            <option value="">Any Month</option>
            <option value="October 2017">October 2017</option>
            <option value="November 2017">November 2017</option>
            <option value="December 2017">December 2017</option>
            <option value="January 2018">January 2018</option>
         </select>
         <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" value="16-Oct-2017" style="">
            <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="...">
     </div>
```

e.g If user click on calendar October 2019 select option to display Oct 2019, because I have my input as `<input type="hidden" />`.

Is that possible or should I just prefer have one of these?

Comment: So, you want: If user select 23-Oct 2017, Dropdown selected option should be October 2017?

Comment: @MayankPatel yes that's right. And even better if I could add another option with day in front of month and change both of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by formatting the date output format (`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "MM yy" );`) and then setting the drop down value(`$('#name_id').val($('#datepicker').val());`).
Try running below code snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   //Below line will set format for date "Month year" .Note This format is custom,according to the drop down value
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "MM yy" );
   //On change of Date from date picker, this will set value in select dropdown
   $('#datepicker').change(function(){
   $('#name_id').val($('#datepicker').val());
        });
  } );
  
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Calendar: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
 

<div class="input-group col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 search">
      <label class="bd-form-label" style="float: left;width: 100%;">Dates</label>
         <select name="name" id="name_id" style="width: 80%;float: left;">
            <option value="">Any Month</option>
            <option value="October 2017">October 2017</option>
            <option value="November 2017">November 2017</option>
            <option value="December 2017">December 2017</option>
            <option value="January 2018">January 2018</option>
         </select>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I select January 2017 in the calendar, January 2017 is not getting inserted into the Dates dropdown.

Comment: Because, Dropdown has static value of January 2018 and not 2017. If you try and select any date date from January 2018, drop down will populate. You can go ahead and add particular month value in the static drop down.

Comment: @AniketWarey i add another select option with day. Is it possible to get  the day as well? I tried by adding  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "d" );
   //On change of Date from date picker, this will set value in select dropdown
   $('#datepicker').change(function(){
   $('#day_id').val($('#datepicker').val());
        });     but is not working

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I want to tell you that I have used the Moment library for the Date interpretation.

You just need to include the below library link in your code(CDN).

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js.

Now, I have used the Jquery ui-Datepicker for the date picker initialization.In it, I have used the **`onSelect`** change event to get the selected date.

Then, I have used the moment to get the month and year in the format `MMMM-YYYY`.

And finally, I have set this option in the drop-down.I also check if option already exists, don't insert it in the dropdown

So, whatever date you will select, that month will be inserted into the drop-down and also selected.

Below is the fiddle link.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nh6eoj03/276/)

Let me know if it fits your requirements.Thanks!

```js
$('#date1').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
    var monthObj=moment(dateText,"MM/DD/YYYY");
    var drop_option=monthObj.format('MMMM YYYY');
    if($("#name_id option[value='"+drop_option+"']").length == 0){
      $('#name_id').append( '<option value="'+drop_option+'">' + drop_option + '</option>');
    }
   $("#name_id option[value='"+drop_option+"']").prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 search">
      <label class="bd-form-label" style="float: left;width: 100%;">Dates</label>
         <select name="name" id="name_id" style="width: 80%;float: left;">
            <option value="">Any Month</option>
            <option value="October 2017">October 2017</option>
            <option value="November 2017">November 2017</option>
            <option value="December 2017">December 2017</option>
            <option value="January 2018">January 2018</option>
         </select>
         <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" value="16-Oct-2017" style="">
            <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="...">
     </div>
     <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> <br/>
```